# Call to WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy taking too long

Tags: wcf

This is quite odd.

I have a windows service that works OK, but when the computer is restarted the service get stuck on a call to WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy for 11 minutes. About 11 minutes, on XP and on Vista, where it was tested so far, all the time. If the computer is connected to the company's domain, it works. But when it's not, I'm facing this issue.

Some other weird things happens on Vista as well. For instance, it doesn't have an active network connection (disconnected) during this time and some other Windows system warnings appears just after these 11 minutes. Before 11 minutes the system seems more or less hanged, waiting for something. 
It's not about my machine, because I've tested it on XP, and Vista, and also on some VMs of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the call to WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy in your case actually tries to connect to some system on your company network to

1. Actually find out if the Proxy server is found
2. Get the script that automatically configures these settings on your system

Please try to use a tool like Fiddler or WireShark to see which outgoing connections are attempted. The url will point out the location it tries to connect to and the reason for the call.